# Set width or resolution for HtmlUnit web client

Tags: htmlunit

Is it possible to set the width or screen resolution of the emulated browser in a HTMLUnit WebClient?

After some Googling, I did find a class in HtmlUnit called `WebWindow`, which contains methods such as `setOuterWidth`, but I am not sure how to use these methods.

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use [WebClientOptions](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClientOptions.html) like this:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.getOptions().setScreenHeight(1024)
```